# Find absolute left position of element inside parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `jQuery`/`JavaScript` in an attempt to create a scroller.

As you would expect, the parent element is constrained by `overflow-x`, so child elements could appear before and after the visible box.

```
(1 hidden) (2 hidden) [ (3 visible) (4 visible) (5 visible) ] (6 hidden)
```

Where the square brackets represent the visible items in the parent.

I'm using `jquery.Position().left` at present which gives me the left position in relation to the parent. So item 3 will be `0` in its current position.

However, I'd like to find the left position in relation to all the parent content - supposing each element was `100px` wide, I'd expect to see `300px`.

I'm neither a `jQuery` nor `JavaScript` expert, so I need a clue as to how to go find the correct function that will return this data.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `jQuery`:
 `$('#element3').offset().left` to get the offset.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. My guess is that  the offset is being compared with the viewport because the value goes up and down when the browser focuses in. If it were being compared with the element parent element, it would always increase when elements got further away.

Comment: It worked for my scenario. Maybe you could share some code? [`jQuery.offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `jquery.prevAll()` to get all elements before the one that's positioned at `0` and add up their `jquery.outerWidth()` (margins included).

Alternatively, can also wrap the slides in an extra div, make that div the offset parent, and get the position relative to that. Besides, most sliders are implemented with a container-and-track setup, not moving each element individually:

```
<div class="parent-with-overflow-x">
  <div class="that-div-i-just-mentioned">
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree with the container/track setup - that works. However the use of the tab key causes the browser to bring hidden items into view, thus breaking tracking. I'm trying to put together a fix for that scenario,